# Query Results Differ In SQL Mgmt and CFQuery

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

executing the following query in SQL management studio provides results, whereas it does not via cfquery...

```
select distinct locationid, locationname, locationaliasname
from vwLocationsWithAlias
where 1 = 0
or (LocationName = N'the' or LocationAliasName = N'the')
or (LocationName = N'the republic' or LocationAliasName = N'the republic')
```

The results expected are returned from SQL Mgmt Studio, but nothing is returned from CFQuery.  WTF!?

Comment: Can you hit the database at all? What do you get from `select count(*) as cnt from vwLocationsWithAlias`?

Comment: Both cfquery and SQL Mgmt Studio return the correct count of 406

Comment: Even a select * works, but only if I do not specify a where clause

Answer (score 2):

Run Profiler while you send the query from Coldfusion and see if it is sending what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its the TransactSQL Unicode indicator ("N") you have on your string constraints.  I suspect the SQL parser in CF doesn't understand that.

Does the CF throw an error, or just not return any rows?

There is a setting in the Datasource control for sql server which tells that the DB is in unicode:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=datasources_ADV_MJS_11.html

Comment: My cfquery is actually using cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" but no matter how I code the sql in cfquery, I get back nothing... I always get back results from sql manager.

Comment: show us the actual query you are using in cfquery.  also, are you getting any errors at all or just no records returned?

Comment: <cfquery datasource="#variables.dsn#" name="qryLocations">
         select distinct locationid, locationname, locationaliasname
            from vwLocationsWithAlias
            where
            <cfset row = 1/>
            <cfloop array="#locationPhrases#" index="m">
             <cfif row gt 1>or</cfif> ( LocationName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#m#" /> or LocationAliasName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#m#" /> )
                <cfset row = row + 1/>
            </cfloop>
        </cfquery>

Comment: that cfquery is not the same query as posted above. what do you get if you execute the above query exactly from cfquery?

Comment: If you add a <cfdump var="#qryLocations#"><cfabort> right after the query, it'll show the SQL (without the bind values, tho) - does it look like you expect?

Comment: Have you enabled unicode on your datasource @ CF administrator?

Comment: I've dumped the query and the SQL is correct.  With or without cfqueryparam, the query returns nothing.

Comment: and if you run the query from the dump in SQL management studio, it works?

Comment: Yessir.  I've narrowed this down to a problem with the use of the array.  What's strange is that if the array is dynamically created it doesn't work.  If the array is manually created, it works.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure its hitting the correct database (not a development db) :)

Comment: I've verified the correct datasource is being hit by outputting the variable.dsn variable as a comment in my sql, which is dumped on output

Comment: It provides a possible answer. Querying the wrong database would result in not getting the expected data. I know i've been victim of that in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try using preserveSingleQuotes around the parts that have the apostrophes..

Comment: Thanks, but there are no apostrophes in my query params

Answer (score 0):

Can I also recommend NOT using distinct as it's a lot slower than using "group by" on large datasets

Comment: Yeah, that might help performance-wise- but it doesn't change the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your fields are nvarchar vs varchar, why not just take out the N'the' and just use 'the' or whatever the data you want in your where clause.

You can also check permissions on your view, to make sure coldfusion user that you use via datasources, is setup to select from that view.

That is the other difference between a coldfusion query and a query analyzer query, it could use different user credentials.

Good Luck.

Comment: this has nothing to do with permissions or datatypes.  I would certainly get an exception if it was either of those things... not a lack of results

Comment: What about users' default schema?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that SSMS and CFQuery have different 'SET' or other per-connection options?  Some of those can affect results.

If you can catch connections open when you start a SQL Profiler trace, you can see a bunch of the connection options when you highlight the "Existing Connection" row.  (Even if you don't catch them open, I have to assume you'd be able to see them when a connection is established and shortly thereafter . . .)  Or, you may be able to get cfquery to `SELECT @@OPTIONS` or `SELECT SESSIONATTRIBUTE(...)`.

I confess I haven't carefully considered your query in light of all possible connection options to have a strong hypothesis - it's just a possible lead.